# How to activate Private Mode for Tezos node

Tags: private-mode, bakery

Tezos has an optional feature called Private Mode which restricts connections to a list of nodes upon startup. How can I activate this function?

Answer (score 6):

The node can be set in private mode with the option `--private-mode`

It doesn’t connect to any peer other than those provided with `--peer` or in bootstrap-peers

Comment: It also doesn't allow connections from peers, so if you were public for a while and went private, it will be log connection rejection messages.